# OnClickListener not fired on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

On my android app project i have to make a button with a ProgressBar on background and two TextView.

I make a first attempt like this:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_touch_1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_touch_1_progress_bar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/button_progress_bar_default"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_touch_1_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="3"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_touch_1_letter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="45dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks good but when i attempt to add an OnClickListener it doesn't work correctly.

```
keyboard_touch_1.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "IT WORKS !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The OnClickListener is not fired and i have no idea of why. It's probably very simple but i doesn't understand why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post complete code

Comment: The complete view is very vig. I post only the part relative with the problem. Do you really need the complete layout ?

Comment: no, just the kotlin code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vmichalak/510063b5925c00c8c633e6c1b2c7258e << The complete kotlin code here

Comment: try removing `android:clickable="false"`

Comment: It change nothing.

Comment: and move `keyboard_touch_1.setOnClickListener {...}` at the end of onresume

Comment: Thanks you it works !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove

```
android:clickable="false"
```

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#clickable)

> Defines whether this view reacts to click events

and move `keyboard_touch_1.setOnClickListener {...}` at the end of `onResume` because 
[`DataBindingUtil.setContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#setContentView(android.app.Activity,%20int))  will reset the previously set layout (`setContentView`) therefore you have a new layout with new views.

Note :  you are using data-binding along with normal initialization `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)` technique so the optimal way would be to use

[**Event Handling via data binding**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#event_handling)

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot comment due to my low rep I will have to post an answer.

Based on the code you have provided via your GitHub link you are actually trying to set the content view twice.

Firstly you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)` within your onCreate() method and then `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_game)` within your onResume() method.

Please try deleting `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)` and then move your data binding setup code to your onCreate method(). You can then access your constraint layout view via your "binding" object as a property.

For example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = GameViewModel()
        val binding: ActivityGameBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_game)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        binding.keyboardTouch1.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "IT WORKS !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.startUpdate()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        viewModel.stopUpdate()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe your layout is include label with id, this id override origin id.

Comment: Oh, great catch! In my case, Android got confused because my ConstraintLayout subclass had an `id` in the XML layout where it was used, but another `id` was also defined in the subclass XML sublayout!